# Upper & lower limits of integration of marginal distribution & density function of continuous random variables

Tags: probability, integration

Marginal distribution function for continuous random variables $X, Y$ looks like:

$$F(x) = \int^x_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \! f(u, y) \, dy \, du$$

Then marginal density function looks like

$$f(x) = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\! f(x, y) \,dy$$

What I am wondering is why is the upper limit of integration of marginal distribution function $x$ and $\infty$ for the other? Is it the same if I use $\infty$ for both? Or if I use $x$ and $y$ instead ($\int^x_{-\infty} \int^{y}_{-\infty}$)?

Similarly for marginal density function if I use $\int^y_{-\infty}$ is it wrong?

I am thinking I am essentialy integrating over the supports of the random variable?

Comment: Did you know that you can write `\int_a^b` rather than `\int^b_a`?

Comment: @dfeuer its the same thing right?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First, you will have to understand the definition of the **marginal density function** of $x$, $f(x)$, being a probability density function averaged over the information of $y$ ie the probability of $x$ when the value of $y$ is unknown. I usually see this as "integrating out the $y$" from the joint distribution function. Hence, you integrate with the limits $[\infty, -\infty]$. This is why you define the marginal density function as shown.

To your first question, you should understand the meaning of $F(x)$, being that $F(x) = \text{P}(X<x)$. If you remember the relationship between the PDF and CDF, the CDF is the integral of the PDF. Hence, $F(x) = \int f(x)dx$. You are actually doing that. The upper limit is definitely $x$ and not $\infty$ because if you integrate with $\infty$ as the upper limit, based on the probability axiom, you get $1$. (Which basically finding the probability of $x$ being any real number)